# Converting my minecraft windows 10 edition to minecraft java edition

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

So, I bought the windows 10 version of minecraft thinking it was the java version, the mod-able. version a while back, don't remember when. I want to know if I am able to somehow swap the windows 10 version for the java version. 
I've looked online for answers, but frustratingly, all the answers I was able to get was how to get the windows 10 version from the java version. This didn't help me at all, as it was the complete opposite of what I wanted.
I currently don't have the funds to grab a whole new copy of java edition, so I was wondering if there was a way to switch them.

Comment: I haven't done the necessary research to verify this, but my guess is no, you can't swap your Windows 10 version for the Java version.  I believe you have to buy the Java Edition separately.  Sorry.

Comment: You should contact Mojang to undo your purchase.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a case for Mojang tech support, not a Q&A site.

Comment: Oops, meant to say "customer support", but now I can't change it anymore. :/

Answer (score 1):

There is currently not a way to "swap" Bedrock Edition for Java Edition.

However, if you contact Mojang support, you can discuss the possibility of getting a refund for Bedrock Edition. If you're able to get that refund, you can then purchase Java Edition.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately its not possible to convert the Windows10 version to the Java edition. It is possible to go the other way around, but that doesn't help here.

Your best bet is getting a refund/exchange from Mojang for the Java edition.